# TortoiseHG commits are very slow

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Commits used to be rather fast, but now they take maybe 10 seconds. Other TortoiseHG operations such as update and push are reasonably fast, but commits have been slow lately. My repo has about 2600 commits; could it need some sort of reindexing to make it faster again? Or is committing always slow on such old repositories?

Answer (score 0):

2600 changesets isn't "big repo" in common. Except ordinary OS-level management tasks, try to check state of repo with `hg verify` and consult [Repository Corruption](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RepositoryCorruption) wiki for possible ways of eliminating of problems

Comment: I ran hg verify and it didn't say if it found any errors or not... does this mean there are no errors, or did it fix them?

Comment: I then ran `hg debugrebuildstate -r tip` and it seems to have helped somewhat, though the only commit I tested was rather small.

Comment: OK, this is interesting... the console says this when I commit (and this operation takes a few seconds): `calling hook commit.lfiles: hgext.largefiles.reposetup.checkrequireslfiles`... will disabling the largefiles extension be OK even though I have some large files in my repo? I'm not committing anything but code at the moment but there are large files in there...

Comment: @ekolis - maybe disabling|removing hook will be better solution?

Comment: Disabling the hook? Like the large files extension? Or something else?